# Not able to cast from a HQL query to the Java Entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a MySQL table with this schema:

```
     Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| keyword     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| synonyms    | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| replacewith | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| isProtected | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| combined    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| stopword    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| oneway      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
```

Now I have an entity class for it in the following manner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "keyword_configuration", catalog = "search")
public class KeywordConfiguration implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3090932150501117578L;
    private Integer id;
    private String keyword;
    private String synonymns;
    private boolean replacewith;
    private boolean isProtected;
    private boolean combined;
    private boolean stopword;
    private boolean oneway;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "keyword")
    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    @Column(name = "synonyms")
    public String getSynonymns() {
        return synonymns;
    }

    public void setSynonymns(String synonymns) {
        this.synonymns = synonymns;
    }

    @Column(name = "replacewith")
    public boolean isReplacewith() {
        return replacewith;
    }

    public void setReplacewith(boolean replacewith) {
        this.replacewith = replacewith;
    }
    @Column(name = "isprotected")
    public boolean isProtected() {
        return isProtected;
    }

    public void setProtected(boolean isProtected) {
        this.isProtected = isProtected;
    }

    @Column(name = "combined")
    public boolean isCombined() {
        return combined;
    }

    public void setCombined(boolean combined) {
        this.combined = combined;
    }

    @Column(name = "stopword")
    public boolean isStopword() {
        return stopword;
    }

    public void setStopword(boolean stopword) {
        this.stopword = stopword;
    }

    @Column(name = "oneway")
    public boolean isOneway() {
        return oneway;
    }

    public void setOneway(boolean oneway) {
        this.oneway = oneway;
    }
}
```

My Hql query to fetch the results is the following:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<KeywordConfigurationDTO> getConfigurationDetails(String keyword) {
    String sQuery = " FROM " + KeywordConfiguration.class.getSimpleName()
            + " WHERE keyword = :word";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sQuery);
    query.setParameter("word", keyword);
    //System.out.println(query.toString());
    System.out.println(query.list().size() + "SIZE");
    return (List<KeywordConfigurationDTO>)query.list();
}
```

Now when I print the size of the query list it gives the right result but as soon as I try to access the object of `List<KeywordConfiguration>` it doesn't access it without giving any error. By debugging I can see that the  correct objects are there in the list. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the version of Hibernate you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `KeywordConfigurationDTO` instead of `KeywordConfiguration`. So your method would be something like this.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<KeywordConfigurationDTO> getConfigurationDetails(String keyword) {
    String sQuery = " FROM " + KeywordConfiguration.class.getSimpleName()
            + " WHERE keyword = :word";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sQuery);
    query.setParameter("word", keyword);
    //System.out.println(query.toString());
    System.out.println(query.list().size() + "SIZE");
    List<KeywordConfiguration> kcList = query.list();

    // You have to implement convertKcToKCDtoLit method to convert KeywordConfiguration to KeywordConfigurationDTO
    List<KeywordConfigurationDTO> kcDtoList = convertKcToKCDtoLit(kcList);

    return kcDtoList;
}
```